# Querying SQL Server using Excel VBA issues

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I am trying to retrieve DISTINCT values using Excel VBA and a SQL Server.  I have established a connection to the DB and can run other queries; however, the following SQL query causes my VBA code to break:

SQL Statement:

```sql
Select DISTINCT ZoneName, IsoName From vDeal 
Where PeriodMonth >= '2015-03-01' 
Order by IsoName, ZoneName ASC
```

Excel VBA:

```vb
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$; & _ 
    Location=LOADZONE_DISTINCT", Destination:=Range("$C$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandText = "Select DISTINCT ZoneName, IsoName From vDeal Where PeriodMonth >= & _
        '2015-03-01' Order by IsoName, ZoneName ASC"
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "LOADZONE_DISTINCT"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

> The field PeriodMonth is a date formatted "yyyy-mm-dd"
>
> Excel error: "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object defined error

The SQL query works perfectly in MS SQL Serve Management Studio, so there must be a breakdown on the Excel side.  Could a reference library be missing on the VBA side, or is it a date formatting issue?

Comment: Did you add these line continuations for the purpose of the post, or the code is identical as in the VBE editor? Because a string literal cannot span multiple lines like this... that code wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

if the code is identical as in the VBE editor then please change this line

```
.CommandText = " Select DISTINCT ZoneName, IsoName From vDeal Where PeriodMonth >= " & _
    " '2015-03-01' Order by IsoName, ZoneName ASC "
```

for reference  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd627355(v=office.12).aspx#Access2007BuildingSQLStatements_UsingStringCriteria

Comment: Sorry that was for readability on the website.  I'll make the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out a different way using ActiveX Data Object.

```
Dim strSql As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection

Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=####;Data Source=####;Initial Catalog=####;User ID=####;Password=####"
conn.ConnectionTimeout = 300
conn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
conn.Open

strSql1 = "Select DISTINCT ZoneName, IsoName From vDeal Where ZoneName Is NOT NULL and IsoName IS NOT NULL and PeriodMonth > '2015-03-01' Order by IsoName, ZoneName ASC"

rs.Open strSql1, conn
If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
    wks.Range(Cells(1, 1).Address).Value = "No Data"
Else
    wks.Range(Cells(1, 1).Address).CopyFromRecordset rs
    For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        wks.Range(Cells(1, 1).Address).Range("A1").Offset(0, i) = rs.Fields.Item(i).Name
    Next i
End If

rs.Close
```

Using Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library in the VBA references.